# 301 Redirect to replace all spaces to hyphens

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

So here's my problem.  I took over a site that has has a bunch of pages indexed that have %20 indexed in Google.  This is simply because the person decided to just use the tag name as the title and url slug.  So, the urls were something like this:

```
http://www.test.com/tag/bob%20hope
http://www.test.com/tag/bob%20hope%20is%20funny
```

I have added a new field for the url slug and string replaced all spaces with dashes.  While I have no problem linking to these new pages and getting the data, I need to 301 redirect the old URLs to the new URLs, which would be something like:

```
http://www.test.com/tag/bob-hope
http://www.test.com/tag/bob-hope-is-funny
```

So, it needs to be able to account for multiple spaces.  Any questions? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use these rules in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# keep replacing space to hyphen until there is no space use internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)[\s%20]+(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=NOSPACE:1]

# when there is no space make an external redirection
RewriteCond %{ENV:NOSPACE} =1
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

This will replace all space characters (`\s` or `%20`) to hyphen `-`

So a URI of `/tag/bob%20hope%20is%20funny` will become `/tag/bob-hope-is-funny` with `301`

**Brief Explanation:** If there are more than 1 space in URI then 1st RewriteRule is fired recursively replacing each space character with hyphen `-` until there is no space left. This rule will only rewrite internally.

Once no space is left 2nd RewriteRule is fired which just uses a `301 redirect` to the converted URI.

Comment: The DPI flag is new to me, so maybe I just don't know how this works, but doesn't this keep rewriting, removing one space at a time, until all of the spaces have been replaced? I supposed that works, but it seems a bit complicated. He also needs it to actually do a 301 redirect, and it doesn't look like this will do that. Correct me if I'm mistaken, though.

Comment: Thanks for adding the explanation! I learn something new on Stack Overflow every day. :)

Comment: what about urls that start with a space? like domain.com/ test  test test         /test

Comment: @PanagiotisGeorgeRaditsas: I believe it should work. If it doesn't please feel free to post a new question with link to this one and leave a comment here. I will sure try to fix that.

Comment: @anubhava Hello once again mate please take a look at this post it describes my issue as I stated above, thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935257/htacces-clean-urls-replacing-whitespaces-and-20-with

Comment: The above answer will also replace any 0 characters with a - in the URL and it relies on falling through the code correctly so it's run again, and it relies on apache 2.4. Replace line 5 with `RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1-$2 [N,E=NOSPACE:1,DPI]` and it will run through the rewrite rules again immediately (the N parameter) and not cause a recursion (DPI)

Comment: It would be really great if this actually worked. My rules look like this:
`RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1-$2 [N,E=NOSPACE:1,DPI]
RewriteCond %{ENV:NOSPACE} =1
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/categories/flexelene-silver-anti-microbial-protected-tubing^ /p/flexelene-mfxag-antimicrobial-tubing/54547 [NE,NC,L,P]`

Comment: @BermudaLamb: It is actually difficult to understand the code and requirements from comments. Please post a new question and we'll attend it.

Answer (score 5):

Building on @anhubhava's answer, it's close, but that will also match %,2 or 0 in the URL, and it can cause a loop on apache 2.2 if you don't use the DPI parameter. The full script should look like this:

```
Options FollowSymlinks MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# keep replacing space to hyphen until there is no space use internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1-$2 [N,E=NOSPACE:1,DPI]

# when there is no space make an external redirection
RewriteCond %{ENV:NOSPACE} =1
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

I've also added the N (Next) parameter as this then forces the rules to be re-evaluated from the start straight after this rule if it matches. If this isn't there, you can get problems if you're using apache as a reverse proxy as it's unlikely that it'll get to the end of the rewrites before something else happens.

Comment: It seems it doesn't work with urls that contain numbers.