# Replace space, %20 and + with hyphens

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [301 Redirect With Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821120/301-redirect-with-spaces)

Right now I'm redirecting every Image hit to the html page which contains the image.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.com/.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (bing.com|google|yahoo|stumbleupon.com|reddit.com|pinterest.com) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)\.(gif|jpg|png)$ /$1.html [R,L]
```

Since the Images often include spaces but the html pages always use hyphens, I need a solution to also replace all spaces, %20 and + symbols with hyphens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[301 Redirect to replace all spaces to hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821120/301-redirect-with-spaces)

Solves the problem

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\s|%20)
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]
```

Comment: wanted to accept, it said I'd have to wait for 2 days ;)

Comment: There is a mistake in 4th (last line). I had to change /$1-$2 to $1-$2