# Get arbitrary user-input keywords directly from URL?

Tags: html, forms, url

I would like to implement this type of on-the-fly functionality, e.g. using PHP.
(Assume my site is *www.mywebsite.com*)

- User types this in the URL bar: *www.mywebsite.com/banana*
- Then, mywebsite.com takes the keyword "*banana*" like an input
  query/argument and looks for the word "*banana*" in a database table.
- If a match is found, it then retrieves the number of calories in a
  banana, and displays it via HTML on *www.website.com/banana*
- If no match is found, it displays the text "No match found" on the
  same webpage.

Is something like this achievable? Or does the keyword always have to be submitted from within a form, and then the website has to generate a *www.website.com/search?q=banana* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a form and submit its inputs in order to get the url to contain parameter values. You can directly write them by yourself and store them in a `<a>` tags. For example: `<a href="http://google.com?q=Hello world">`

The above example is equivalent of creating a form with `GET` method and writing `hello world` inside it's input of `name="q"`

To avoid the parameter to appear after `/?q=`, you can use create an .htaccess file that translates link like this:
 `example.com/hellow-world` to `example.com/index.php?name=hello-world`

The .htaccess file content will look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?name=$1
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do translations with customized rules like this. Perhaps I can even do whitespace-translation with this? (i.e., if user types "banana smoothie", I would have it auto-rewrite to "banana-smoothie" or something similar, to make it safe.)

Comment: Yes look this question has the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803187/solved-replace-space-20-and-with-hyphens @boardbite

Answer (score 3):

Make an `.htaccess` file and add this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ search.php?q=$1
```