# 301 Redirect for URL With Spaces

Tags: .htaccess

I have a situation where I want to redirect all the incoming URL with %20 in the URL to be replaced with - for all occurrences.

Now I get this link -

> [301 Redirect to replace all spaces to hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821120/301-redirect-with-spaces)

which gives this solution

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\s|%20)
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]
```

which works perfect but there is one small issue with this solution. This also redirects the request for images/docs/pdf or other resources and results in 404

Can i have something which will redirect only certain sections and not all incoming links like it will replace and redirect only for

```
www.test.com/colleges/this%20is%20my%20link/123 to
www.test.com/colleges/this-is-my-link/123
or
www.test.com/schools/this%20is%20my%20link/123 to
www.test.com/schools/this-is-my-link/123
```

and leave all other requests intact??

Comment: `%{THE_REQUEST}` always contains spaces, for the simple fact that it has the structure of `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|bmp|pdf|docx?|txt|css|js)$ - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava - this dosent seems to solve the issue.

I added - 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|ico|bmp|pdf|doc|docx|txt|css|js)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
    RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]

you can visit http://www.oureducation.in/Colleges/Education/Education/61/85 to check the output

Comment: this seems to be working - i am testing it. Thanks a lot 

I hv a small query - will it also take care of files with extensions in CAPS like JPG

Comment: Yes it will. Flag `NC` is there for `no case` comparison.

Comment: dont we need #RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\s|%20) as per your solution in another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821120/301-redirect-with-spaces

Comment: No I now realize its not needed. Don't recall why I wrote it last time.

Answer (score 0):

That all seems awfully complex for what you want to do.  In theory (!!) apache should unescape the `%20` characters and replace them with a space in the string you're trying to match, so the following should work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\ ]+)\ (.*)$ $1-$2 [N]
```

It basically splits any requested URI into non-space character, followed by space, followed by anything, and rewrites the space to be a `-`.  It then repeats all rewrites (`[N]`) so that it can replace the next space, until it doesn't match.

If the issue is that sometimes you have an actual file that has spaces, and you want to access that, just prefix with a condition that states it will only do the redirect if you're not accessing an actual file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\ ]+)\ (.*)$ $1-$2 [N]
```