# htaccess clean urls & replacing whitespaces and %20 with -

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm strugling to make this work. At the moment my htaccess contains the following code:

```
#Debugging - Error reporting
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on

#Commpression
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c="">
    <filesmatch ".(js|css|html|png|jpg|jpeg|swf|bmp|gif|tiff|ico|eot|svg|ttf|woff|pdf)$"="">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesmatch>
</ifmodule>

Options All -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\s|%20)
    RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
    RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(png|jpg|bmp|gif|css|js)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+/?.+)$ /index.php?req=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Everything works great except 1 thing if I try this url for example:

```
http://www.domain.com/ test/
```

the browser translates it like to: http://www.domain.com/%20test/
basically after the domain if the path starts with a whitespace or a %20 it fails.
can anyone please point to a solution where the starting spaces will be removed ?

**UPDATE**

The goal:

```
www.domain.com/   this is a      test      /   hello there     /
```

or

```
www.domain.com/   this is a      test
```

to

`www.domain.com/this-is-a-test/` or `www.domain.com/this-is-a-test/hello-there`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am guilty of writing that code more than 2 years back :P

That can be hugely simplified by this code:

```
# remove spaces from start or after /
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)[\s%20]+(.+)$ $1$2 [L]

# remove spaces from end or before /
RewriteRule ^(.+?)[\s%20]+(/.*|)$ $1$2 [L]

# replace spaces by - in between
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1-$2 [L,R]
```

**PS:** Must add that you need to fix the source of these URLs also because it is really not normal to be getting URLs like this.

Comment: Yes I saw that code on an answer of yours here in stackoverflow.
Is there a way to remove any starting whitespaces completely?
ex: www.domain.com/ a test becomes www.comain.com/-a-test. Is it possible to make it www.domain.com/a-test ?

Comment: Thanks for raising this, since `DPI` flag is not really needed in newer Apache versions.

Comment: also www.domain.com/    hello there/   becomes www.domain.com/----hello-there//

Comment: Oh so you just want to remove starting spaces?

Answer (score -1):

This is works fine

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    ModPagespeed on
    ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace,remove_comments
</IfModule>
```