# php rewrite using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite my url

```
http://midogames.com/game.php?id=%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%A9%20%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B0%D9%87%D8%A8
```

to

```
http://midogames.com/%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%A9%20%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B0%D9%87%D8%A8
```

"please note they are spaces in the link"
i am doing this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+) /game.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

but it did not work with me, any suggetion

Comment: `RewriteRule FROM TO` - you should match with FROM and rearange in TO - your code does the opposite of what you want (you rewrite to `/game.php`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `NE` flag:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+game\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ game.php?id=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

Comment: That type of comment never helps, you need to provide all the details. What url did you use to test it? And where is your .htaccess located?

Comment: sorry man, i use the same url as in my question and the .htaccess in the root of midogames.com

Comment: There is a reason I suggested you provide details. Your question has 2 URLs `http://midogames.com/game.php?id=%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%A9%20%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B0%D9%87%D8%A8` AND `http://midogames.com/%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%A9%20%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B0%D9%87%D8%A8` now you tell me which one did you use to test? Also do you more rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: i use http://midogames.com/game.php?id=%D9%84%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%A9%20%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B0%D9%87%D8%A8
 no more rules

Comment: did u have any idea how can i replace 20% "space" by slash -

Comment: Are there multiple instances of `%20` in your URI?

Comment: ok check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935257/htaccess-clean-urls-replacing-whitespaces-and-20-with/18935412#18935412

Comment: Place it below `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: can you please check my site now there is a problem on it when i enter any game

Comment: Because of language issues I am unable to understand what the real problem is. I suggest you create a new question if this seems not helpful.

Comment: i need to add trailing slash at the end of urls can u help me please