# Removing spaces and html special characters from URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a bit help with .htaccess file and URL rewriting. I was searched all question and answers here and i'm stuck with it.

So i need a help with replacing white spaces %20 with **-** to make a SEO friendly URL's.

Current URL http://localhost/blog/Blog%20of%20the%20day

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
# Removes .php extension from inner_blog.php
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ blog.php [NC]
# Remove inner_blog.php and changing it to blog/articlename
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)$ /inner_blog.php?title=$1 [L]
# Need to replace %20 with - from URL
# Current URL http://localhost/blog/Blog%20of%20the%20day
# Need to be  http://localhost/blog/Blog-of-the-day
# Was like    http://localhost/inner_blog.php?title=Blog%20of%20the%20day
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Start or After "/"
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)[\s%20]+(.+)$ $1$2 [L]

// End or Before "/"
RewriteRule ^(.+?)[\s%20]+(/.*|)$ $1$2 [L]
```

I encountered this issue on a previous project and got the answer from this thread.

For Reference: [htaccess clean urls & replacing whitespaces and %20 with -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935257/htaccess-clean-urls-replacing-whitespaces-and-20-with)

Comment: ok i have replace whitespace with - but still i m not geeting clean url