# htaccess rule to remove and fix spaces in URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have spaces in my URL that I need to remove with an htaccess rule.

here is an example URL:

```
http://www.example.com/folder name/where/else/we-want-here/
http://www.example.com/my folder name/where/else/we-want-here/
```

should be set to:

```
http://www.example.com/foldername/where/else/we-want-here/
http://www.example.com/myfoldername/where/else/we-want-here/
```

and then keep processing more rules.

This is the rule i was playing with, but it needs to be more general since "folder name" could be "my folder name" or other to have 1 or more (or none) spaces in it.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)\ ([a-z0-9-_]+)/(.*)/? /$1$2/$3/ [NC]
```

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Dennis

---

```
## UPDATE ##
```

1) They are %20, though in the URL bar they are spaces.  Sorry for the confusion there.

2) This does partly fix the issue - i cannot get it to work if there is more than 1 space (%20) in the URL.  **[301 Redirect to replace all spaces to hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821120/301-redirect-with-spaces)**

3) I think i semi fixed this. This works:

```
RewriteRule ^washington\sdc(.*) /washingtondc$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

how do I combine to accept a variety of things to match in the front part? I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^(washington\sdc|atlantic\scity)(.*) /$1$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```

but it would not work. thoughts?

Thanks for the input everyone.

Dennis

Comment: Is it possible to do a replace: space for nothing? It would be simplier.

Comment: yes, replacing the space with nothing (removing the space) is exactly what I need.  I could probably work with replace the space with a dash since I can run another rule below it to fix that, but rather skip the step.  thx!

Comment: You actually have _incoming_ URIs with spaces? That shouldn't be happening... they should be either + or %20. They will be translated to spaces at some point. If these are _outgoing_ URIs from your site (`<a>` links), you have to take care of that yourself -- .htaccess doesn't handle them.

Comment: Yeah, we do.  We had an error at some point on my site and some URLs had spaces.  Google picked them up and is coming in to my site at the old URLs with spaces.  It's a pain and I just want to fix them so I do not get error messages anymore. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it all with a single rule, but the rewrite engine loops so you can just use one rule but you must be able to match extra spaces:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)\ ([^/]+)/(.*)/? /$1$2/$3/ [L]
```

And the rule will loop and continue to remove spaces until there aren't anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a space substitution as you already do

```
RewriteRule ^(\S+)\s+(.+)$ $1$2 [L]
```

This pattern looks for leading non-white space `(\S+)`, then one or more white space `\s+` and anything `(.+)` after that.

The problem with this solution is, it is pretty expensive. This is, because it loops until all spaces are removed, which might take several rounds through the rewrite engine.

Comment: Just tried this - neither works.  I wish it was as easy as REPLACE(" ","")!! :)

Comment: I am still hacking away at a fix here.  Something is up though.  I cannot even get this rule to work:

    RewriteRule ^new%20york%20city(.*) /newyorkcity$1 [NC]

Answer (score 0):

Try these 2 rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" $1$2 [L]
RewriteRule "^(\S*) (\S*)$" /$1$2 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: It does work. I posted it after proper testing. You may have some conflicting rule.

Comment: Still trying to fix this one.  Are the quotes supposed to be in there?  tried with and without as the FIRST rule in the HTACCESS and still does not work.  the rewrite URL is coming in as: /washington%20dc/events/11/dancing/  I even tested this but will not work:  RewriteRule ^new%20york%20city(.*) /newyorkcity$1 [NC]

Comment: I think i semi fixed this.  

This works:

RewriteRule ^washington\sdc(.*) /washingtondc$1 [NC,R=301,L]

how do I combine to accept a variety of things to match in the front part?  I tried RewriteRule ^(washington\sdc|atlantic\scity)(.*) /$1$2 [NC,R=301,L] but it would not work.  thoughts?  thx!

Comment: Difficult to read your code from comments. Can you post the code in question and rephrase your question to make it easy to understand.

Comment: ok can you provide me a sample URL for which this code didn't work?

Comment: /washington dc/events/11/dancing/  it turns in to an infinite loop.  Probably because it is not actually replacing the space.

Comment: With my suggested rule `http://domain.com/washington%20dc/events/11/dancing/` became `http://localhost/washingtondc/events/11/dancing/` in my browser.