# 301 Redirect with multi spaces

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have some links like below:

```
http://mysite.ltd/content/store/tag/business card
http://mysite.ltd/content/store/tag/new business card
http://mysite.ltd/content/store/tag/new red card 3
```

Now I want 301 redirect these links to:

```
http://mysite.ltd/content/store/tag/business-card
http://mysite.ltd/content/store/tag/new-business-card
http://mysite.ltd/content/store/tag/new-red-card-3
```

So I try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)[\s%20]+(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=NOSPACE:1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:NOSPACE} =1
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821120/301-redirect-with-spaces). But URL redirected to this link:

```
http://mysite.ltd/tag/new%20business%20card/?%1-%2
```

What's wrong on this code?

Comment: Rules work fine for me

Comment: What was the original URL you entered in browser? I don't see `?%1-%2` getting added anywhere. Can you test in a new broswer?

Comment: @JonLin Did you checked on Apache?

Comment: @anubhava Well, I'll check it.

Comment: "**`Did you checked on Apache?`**" Apache would be the assumption because you are using `.htaccess` and `Apache` directives. So I'm sure Jon was.

Comment: Yes, apache 2.2, vanilla install with mod_rewrite enabled

Comment: I found the problem, when I check with sub-domain or sub-folder code doesn't work. But it works on root.

Comment: That still doesn't explain `/?%1-%2` appearing in URL

Comment: Maybe that was browser cache! I'm not sure.