# replacing #(hash) with _ (underscore) in URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this below URL and all `#` symbols needs to replaced with `_`

http://localhost/test/my#module/my#index.php?param2=10&param2=10

i tried below .htaccess code, but not working. I searched a lot for solution , but none of them are working.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
# keep replacing space to hyphen until there is no space use internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^([#]*)[#]+(.*)$ $1-$2 [E=NOSPACE:1]
# when there is no space make an external redirection
RewriteCond %{ENV:NOSPACE} =1
RewriteRule ^([#]+)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Please let me how can fix this issue.

Comment: `#` and part after that is not sent to web server

Comment: @anubhava, sorry i did not get you . You mean to to day that `#` and part after that will be ignored. Actually i tried your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821120/301-redirect-to-replace-all-spaces-to-hyphens , but not working for me.

Comment: That answer is not for `#`. Browser doesn't send any text starting with `#` to web server.

Comment: I mean to say that i tried the same examples with space not with #.  My issue is that we are sending URLs via SMS to user . If the urls have `_` then they are getting replaced by `space` there by breaking URLs in SMS. So we need alternative to `_` in the url. So once the user hits that URLs then using htaccess we planning to replace alternate character with `_`.   We can not use `&` and `%` . Can you please suggest on this ??

Comment: I suggest you update the question with these requirements. And clarify what is original URL and what is redirected one you desire to be.