# Redirecting a SEO friendly URL to a URL with variables

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

I am trying to rewrite a dynamic URL with .htaccess but can't seem to get this to work. The original URL is presented like this:

```
https://myurl.com/supplier/my-supplier-number-one/
```

And I need it to forward as:

```
https://myurl.com/suppliers?ID=my supplier number one
```

But instead I am getting:

```
https://myurl.com/suppliers?ID=my-supplier-number-one/
```

I need to remove the spaces and the / at the end of the line. Right now I have:

```
RewriteRule ^supplier/(.*)$ /supplier?ID=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also, this is on a wordpress site where in the .htaccess I have this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^supplier/(.*)$ /supplier?ID=$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is that an OK placement for my line of code or should it be somewhere else?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: _"need to remove [...] the / at the end of the line"_ - put the slash outside of the capturing group then.

Comment: _"remove the spaces"_ - [301 Redirect to replace all spaces to hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5821120/1427878)

Comment: _"Is that an OK placement for my line of code"_ - working with WordPress, you should really place your own additions outside the `BEGIN WORDPRESS` / `END WORDPRESS` comments that should be in that file to begin with. WordPress will replace anything between those two comments, when the permalink settings get flushed.